# I have 6 matrices and I have to perform a t-test over cell values combined from the 6 matrices and store the p-value in a new matrix

Tags: r, matrix, t-test

Input:
There are 6 input matrices of same dimensions
3 input matrices from normal tissues:

```
              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          31                  4           
GeneB           5                  8 

              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA           5                 14           
GeneB           5                  8 


              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          30                 14           
GeneB           45                 7
```

3 input matrices from cancer tissues:

```
              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          11                  4           
GeneB           5                  18 

              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA           7                 14           
GeneB           15                 4 


              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          30                 14           
GeneB           45                 7
```

output:

```
                  GeneA                            GeneB          
GeneA        t-test({31,5,30},{11,7,13})    t-test({4,14,14},{4,14,14})        
GeneB        t-test({5,5,45},{5,15,45})     t-test({8,8,7},{18,4,7})
```

Output matrix will have the p-values from the test

Comment: Hi @Nikita please add the question.

Comment: What are you testing, what do you want to highlight? What do contigency tables represent?

Comment: I m testing gene expression across normal and cancer tissue types

Comment: Please post data in `dput` format. Do the matrices have names following a pattern? Even if two groups of patterns, for normal and cancer data?

Comment: No there  is no such pattern, but I can change their names to create a pattern over the two groups

Answer (score 1):

The code that follows conducts the t-tests on data in a 3-dim array form. This makes it easier to loop through the data sets, extract the required vectors and run the tests.

## From tabular data to arrays

```
normal <- mget(ls(pattern = "^normal"))
cancer <- mget(ls(pattern = "^cancer"))

anorm <- array(dim = c(dim(normal[[1]]), length(normal)))
acanc <- array(dim = c(dim(cancer[[1]]), length(cancer)))
for(i in seq_along(normal)) {
  anorm[, , i] <- unlist(normal[[i]])
  acanc[, , i] <- unlist(cancer[[i]])
}
```

---

## The t-tests

Create a results list first, then run the tests, then extract the p-values into a data.frame.

```r
t_test_list <- vector("list", length = prod(dim(anorm)[1:2]))
for(j in seq(dim(anorm)[2])) {
  for(i in seq(dim(anorm)[1])) {
    x <- anorm[i, j, ]
    y <- acanc[i, j, ]
    k <- i + dim(anorm)[1]*(j - 1)
    t_test_list[[k]] <- t.test(x, y)
  }
}

t_test_pval <- normal[[1]]
t_test_pval[] <- sapply(t_test_list, `[[`, 'p.value')

t_test_pval
#>           GeneA     GeneB
#> GeneA 0.6176386 1.0000000
#> GeneB 0.8618120 0.6850214
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
x<-'              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          31                  4           
GeneB           5                  8'
normal1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

x<-'              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA           5                 14           
GeneB           5                  8 '
normal2 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)


x<-'              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          30                 14           
GeneB           45                 7 '
normal3 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

x<-'              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          11                  4           
GeneB           5                  18 '
cancer1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

x<-'              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA           7                 14           
GeneB           15                 4 '
cancer2 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)


x<-'              GeneA             GeneB          
GeneA          30                 14           
GeneB           45                 7 '
cancer3 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the neatest way to this is to bind both sets of matrices into 2 x 2 x 3 arrays, then use `Map` to get the t tests at each of the four combinations.

Let's say your matrices are called `norm1`, `norm2`, `norm3` for the normal tissue and `ca1`, `ca2` and `ca3` for the cancer tissue. Then we can do:

```r
library(abind)

norm <- abind::abind(norm1, norm2, norm3, along = 3)
canc <- abind::abind(ca1, ca2, ca3, along = 3)

pvals <- Map(function(i, j) {
  t.test(norm[i, j, ], canc[i, j, ])$p.val
  }, i = c(1:2, 1:2), j = c(1, 1, 2, 2))

matrix(unlist(pvals), 2, dimnames = dimnames(norm1))
#>           GeneA     GeneB
#> GeneA 0.6176386 1.0000000
#> GeneB 0.8618120 0.6850214
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
norm1 <- structure(c(31L, 5L, 4L, 8L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    c("GeneA", "GeneB"), c("GeneA", "GeneB")))

norm2 <- structure(c(5L, 5L, 14L, 8L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    c("GeneA", "GeneB"), c("GeneA", "GeneB")))

norm3 <- structure(c(30L, 45L, 14L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    c("GeneA", "GeneB"), c("GeneA", "GeneB")))

ca1 <- structure(c(11L, 5L, 4L, 18L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    c("GeneA", "GeneB"), c("GeneA", "GeneB")))

ca2 <- structure(c(7L, 15L, 14L, 4L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    c("GeneA", "GeneB"), c("GeneA", "GeneB")))

ca3 <- structure(c(30L, 45L, 14L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    c("GeneA", "GeneB"), c("GeneA", "GeneB")))
```

Comment: Instead of abind, as it only takes 3 matrices, can i use  something else as the number of matrices may increase to 5

Comment: It can take any number of matrices @NikitaSrivastav

Comment: Also, my matrices are sized 1000*1000 each, so for the map function pvals <- Map(function(i, j) {
  t.test(norm[i, j, ], canc[i, j, ])$p.val
}, i = c(1:1000, 1:1000), j = c(1, 1, 2, 2))

Comment: For matrices 1000 * 1000 you would have `i = rep(1:1000, 1000)` and `j = rep(1:1000, each = 1000)`

Comment: And you will end up with 1 million p values!